# Works in the console but not in the editor

Tags: javascript, console, editor, setattribute

I am practicing JavaScript with a program that should change the image of a dice according to a random number.
If I put this line in the console the images changes; it works.

```js
document.querySelector("img.img1").setAttribute("src", "images/dice1.png");
```

but if I put it in the editor I get the following error message:

> index.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setAttribute')
> at index.js:5

Why?

Comment: Please show how you tried to do this with a query selector. It should be just as plain as doing a query and then setting the src or the queried element. Please provide an [mre]

Comment: I wrote the line in the comment already
document.querySelector("img.img1").setAttribute("src", "images/dice1.png");
the only active line in the index.js file.

Comment: OK, now add the HTML on which you are trying to call this query.  The issue could be in either the JS or the HTML.  I highly encourage you to make a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I found what was the problem I forgot differ the link of the js link file in the head. I will see about how to do a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot differ the link of the js link file in the head.
I put this line

```html
<script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

only in the head of the html file. I should differ it or put it in the end of the body section.

Comment: If you don't format HTML as a code block, it gets rendered as HTML and can't be seen. Your answer could also be a lot clearer.